# SCNPhysicsVehicle SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel Road Issue

Tags: swift, scenekit, game-physics, arkit

I am testing on a little car game using Apple's [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit), to simulate the car behavior I'm using [SCNPhysicsVehicle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsvehicle) class.

For the first development steps I drove the car on a big area. This worked fine. I've set up all the car variables so that it felt like expected.

In the next step I wanted to build the road. Naturally the road should consist of parts so I can create different racing tracks.

Here is where the trouble begins.

I just made a straight road consisting of 50 blocks. The blocks line up a 100% perfect.

Anyway the car bumps and "jumps" in every place where two road blocks meet.

For better understanding I made a [Video showing the wired behavior](https://youtu.be/X0eS2G5_RlE).

Did anyone ran in the same issue? What I'm doing wrong?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the physics properties of your blocks?  Even if you defaulted, they still exist.  Take a look at the many properties, such as restitution etc.  Hope that helps

Comment: Hello Voltan, thanks for your answer! I've tried around and now it works! Thank you very much

Comment: Excellent, those aren't easy to play around with.  Worked on a pool game one time, drove me nuts.  :)